# Problems with IGBT driving

Tags: pwm, igbt

this is my first question, so please be patient with me :-)

The problem is with IGBT we are using, IRG4PC40S datasheet available here> [link](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/235883.pdf)

It has to control a 1kW heat block to keep a temperature at given level, regulated by PID based script on an atmel microcontroler. The gate of IGBT is switching with PWM on frequency 200Hz with 12VDC over 4,4kOhm resistor. Before the collector is a diode bridge with capacitor array (2mF), to give over all 230VAC phases the same power during the regulation.

It was working quite well, but sometimes it happens that the IGBT breaks trough; any ideas how to get rid off this?

EDIT: added schema [image]

Comment: Are you saying that you have a 4.4K resistor in series with the gate of the IGBT?  Your description isn't clear, could you post a schematic?

Comment: If 4.4K series it would switch very slowly which could cause problems, also the 600V rating is a bit low for 400V use- any inductance in the heater could cause issues when you switch quickly!

Comment: Hi, schematic uploaded. I forgot last time to mention, that there is 10k resistor before the gate.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the greatest of gate-drives.

What you basically have is 4k4 for Turn-ON  (PC817 pulls the gate resistor up to 12V) and 10k for Turn-OFF (a simple gate termination resistor)

These are huge values and you would normally expect to see TurnOn and TurnOFF resistances in the order of 10's of Ohms.

There is equally no freewheel diode across the load. Even a resistor has inductance and thus force commutating an inductive load without a circulation path will cause voltage spikes (possibly to breakdown if the stray capacitance cannot squash it).

You are probably being saved from any overshoot via the HUGE turnOFF time, essentially using the IGBT as a linear resistor

What is probably happening is the IGBT has dissipated too much power due to the large switching losses and finally failed.

Advice

1. Include a freewheel diode for the load
2. Change the gatedrive topology - still use that OPTO but use a BJT push-pull stage to provide a low impedance to the IGBT